# Converting to a ValueFromPipeline function powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

So I have a function called 'Get-SomeValueFromSomewhere'. I'd like to be able to pipe values into it as follows:

1. ```
   'entry1','entry2' | Get-SomeValueFromSomewhere
   ```
2. ```
   Get-SomeValueFromSomewhere -parameter1 'entry1','entry2'
   ```

The function is below, but I'm not sure how to make it support piping. At the moment I'm getting an error 'Cannot process argument transformation on parameter parameter1. Cannot convert value to type System.string.'

```
function Get-SomeValueFromSomewhere {
    [OutputType([string])]
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string[]]$parameter1,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $false)]
        [string]$parameter2
    )

    Process {
        # do all of the processing here   
    }
}
```

Any and all help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Neither `'entry1','entry2' | Get-SomeValueFromSomewhere` or `Get-SomeValueFromSomewhere -parameter1 'entry1','entry2'` produces the error you mention. Please show us the exact input you're providing to the command.

Comment: So you want to bind both values to both parameters?

Comment: That error is probably coming from passing an _array_ as argument to the `string` parameter.

Comment: [1] please post the ENTIRE EXACT error msg in your Question ... and wrap it i code format markers to make it easy to read. ///// [2] why do you list so many versions of powershell? if you need v2, then remove the others ... otherwise, list the actual minimum version you need.

Comment: You've made parameter2 **required** (`Mandatory = $true`) but you're not feeding that parameter to the function. All you send it is an array for parameter1..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to use a function by either providing the values by parameter or by the pipeline like so:

```
"a", "b", "c" | Get-Something  -Param2 "d" -Verbose
Get-Something -Param1 "a", "b", "c" -Param2 "d" -Verbose
```

You could define a function which invokes itself again if the values are provided by parameter. But on the next invocation the parameter `Param1` is piped to the function instead.

```
function Get-Something {
    [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string[]]$Param1,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$Param2
    )
    
    begin {
        if (-Not $PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.ExpectingInput) {
            Write-Verbose "`$Param1 received by parameter, using it as pipeline input instead."
            $PSBoundParameters.Remove('Param1') | Out-Null
            $Param1 | & $MyInvocation.MyCommand @PSBoundParameters
            break
        }
        Write-Verbose "begin"
    }
    
    process {
        Write-Host "$_"
    }
    
    end {
        Write-Verbose "end"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to have multiple distinct parameters the simple answer is to remove the array option from your first parameter, and assigning [position arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.2#position-argument), and using ValueFromRemain like so

```
function Get-SomeValueFromSomewhere {
    [OutputType([string])]
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position=0)]
        [string]$parameter1,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline  = $true, Position=1)]
        [string]$parameter2
    )

    Process {
        # do all of the processing here   
    }
}
```

If you are attempting to run your Get-SomeValueFromSomewhere twice, once against entry1 and then again on entry2 then you will need a [ForEach loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.2)

```
function Get-SomeValueFromSomewhere {
    [OutputType([string])]
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string[]]$parameter1
    )

    Process {
        foreach($entry in $parameter1){
             Write-Output $entry
             # do all of the processing here   
        }

    }
}
```